# Como inserir o valor do datepicker de um icone html <i> dentro do input utilizando Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, input, materialize, datepicker

Sou novo aqui xp.

Como inserir o valor do datepicker de um icone html  dentro do input utilizando javascript?

Estou utilizando o datepicker do matelialize versão 0.100.2 e Vue.js, já corrigi o Bug das versões atuais do Google Chrome, se eu colocar a classe datepicker dentro da tag input funciona perfeitamente, mas preciso que ele receba do icone para deixar o campo input digitável.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
                  <div class="col s6 m4 l4">
                    <div class="input-field">
                      <i class="material-icons datepicker prefix" style="cursor:pointer;" id="dataAdmis"  ref="dataAdmis" name="dataAdmis" @click="insereValornoInput()" >date_range</i>                              
                      <input placeholder="Data de admissão *" id="dataAdmis2" v-mask="'##/##/####'" v-model="dataAdmissaoFunc" type="text" required="true" />
                      <span class="helper-text" data-error="" ></span>
                    </div>  
                  </div>
```

Vou disponibilizar aqui embaixo o código para correção do Bug da versão do Google Chrome, para quem precisar, ou quiser testar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datepicker').on('mousedown .datepicker', (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault (); 
  }), 
  $('.datepicker').on('mousedown .select-dropdown', (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault (); 
  }), 
  $('.datepicker').on('change select', (e) => { 
  $ ('select'). material_select (); 
  }), 

  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        months: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabádo'],
        weekdaysShort: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabádo'],
        weekdaysLetter: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S'],
        today: 'Hoje',
        clear: 'Limpar',
        cancel: 'Sair',
        close: 'Ok',
        labelMonthNext: 'Próximo mês',
        labelMonthPrev: 'Mês anterior',
        labelMonthSelect: 'Selecione um mês',
        labelYearSelect: 'Selecione um ano',
        closeOnSelect: true, 
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 65,
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        container: 'header', 

  })
})
```

Comment: Vc quer pegar o valor de um atributo que está no ícone e colocar dentro do input quando o cara clicar no ícone é isso? Sendo que esse valor do atributo do ícone que vc quer vêm dinamicamente de algum lugar?

Comment: isso mesmo, após clicar no icone abre um datepicker, ai ao selecionar a data o valor seja fixado no campo input

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema acontece apenas nessa versão do materialize (0.100.2) não é só com datepicker, o select também não carrega o evento '@change', depois de um dia pesquisando e testando achei uma solução, vou postar aqui caso alguém tenha a mesma dificuldade. segue:

```
mounted(){ 
 this.carregaSelects();
```

},

methods: {

```
carregaSelects: function(){    
     var self = this;
    //Aqui ele intercepta o evento @change do select
    $('#naturalidadeUf').change(function() {
      var varURL = $("option:selected", this).val();
      self.naturalidadeUf = varURL;
      self.carregaCidadesComplementos(varURL);
    });
    //Aqui ele altera o valor da variável de acordo com a seleção do datepicker
    $('#dataAdmis').change(function() {
      var varURL =  document.getElementById("dataAdmis").value
      self.dataAdmissaoFunc = varURL;
    });
}
```

}